# cephadm - how to separate ssh network from monitor network

Tags: ssh, ansible, ceph

In my company, for several years we were using Ceph while using ceph-ansible as the deployer (and for upgrade, scale operations, etc). Recently I was assigned to migrating to 'cephadm' for installation and for day-2 operations too.

While doing a POC, I experienced 2 issues, one of them more accute than the other:

1. We have different separated networks that were relevant for ceph-ansible:

a. provisioning network, used for ssh and for running tasks remotely at ceph-related hosts (nodes with mons/osds/clients)

b. public network - used for nodes that host the mons,mgrs,mdss. These addresses are **not ssh-able**. Our Ceph clusters worked this way perfectly.

c. cluster network - used for internal ceph traffic like heartbeat, replication, etc. Also not ssh-able.

So with cephadm, when bootstrapping it forces me to 'combine' the public network and the provisioning. In other words, unless I allow this network to be ssh-able (which for security reasons we prefer not to do that), the bootstrap command will fail with the bellow message. I couldn't find a way to install the ceph cluster with separate networks for ssh and for ceph purposes (public network for monitors):

```
/usr/bin/ceph: stderr   File "/usr/share/ceph/mgr/orchestrator/_interface.py", line 225, in raise_if_exception
/usr/bin/ceph: stderr     e = pickle.loads(c.serialized_exception)
/usr/bin/ceph: stderr TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'hostname' and 'addr'
/usr/bin/ceph: stderr
ERROR: Failed to add host <HOSTNAME>: Failed command: /usr/bin/podman run --rm --ipc=host --stop-signal=SIGTERM --net=host --entrypoint /usr/bin/ceph --init -e CONTAINER_IMAGE=<registry:port>/ceph/daemon:quincy-rockylinux-8-x86_64 -e NODE_NAME=<hostname> -e CEPH_USE_RANDOM_NONCE=1 -v /var/log/ceph/a0a19cd2-44ec-11ee-a922-ec0d9a94e986:/var/log/ceph:z -v /tmp/ceph-tmpb0u6hlv7:/etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring:z -v /tmp/ceph-tmpooy56ocy:/etc/ceph/ceph.conf:z <registry:port>/ceph/daemon:quincy-rockylinux-8-x86_64 orch host add <HOSTNAME> <IP>
```

2. We used the original ceph services with names like 'ceph-mon@hostname.service'. With cephadm, each service and each container name has to have the fsid as part of the name. I tried searching where this could be changed but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

1. That's how cephadm works, it requires ssh access to all nodes to be able to run all the checks and remote commands. Since it provides an orchestrator to manage the cluster remotely, there's no way around it.
2. Regarding the service names: with cephadm you can run your Ceph clusters in containers which enables you to run multiple clusters on the same hardware servers. If you didn't have the fsid in the service you wouldn't be able to distinguish the clusters. Is there any specific reason to not want the fsid in the service name? It doesn't really hurt, and [converting an existing cluster](https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/cephadm/adoption/) to cephadm will automatically configure the services for you.